# Private keys not stored on Full Node

Tags: transactions, private-key, nodes, full-node

Is it possible not to load private keys for the wallet on a Full Node and sign the TXs elsewhere, then broadcast signed TXs from the Node?

Comment: yes. Very much yes. The idea gos into wallets like ledger or nano, or directly cold storage. There is plenty of information on "cold storage" in the forum and on bitcointalk.org. Also you can use online webpages from blockchain.info and similiar, to send the tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create raw transactions and sign them offline. However I think you mean a more user friendly way of doing this. The only full node software that I know of which supports offline signing in the GUI is Armory.

Another option is electrum but it's not a full node client.

Comment: So, you still have to have like a single private key generated (or imported before sync?) for the Full Node running under official Bitcoin Core/bitcoind software? And no, I a developer, so I don't expect user-friendliness. Have yet to touch the node itself.

Comment: Core will automatically create a wallet the first time you run it unless you disable that functionality (-disablewallet command line switch). The wallet will have a deterministic extended private key and 100 or so derived address-specific private keys. As for importing private keys later you can do that it's just that Core will have to rescan the blockchain to find transactions relevant to the newly imported private keys. If it has the whole blockchain downloaded already it can do that faster than if you've enabled pruning.